# Installing red carpet -v '3.3.3'

Tags: github-pages, redcarpet

I currently have Redcarpet 3.1.2, using OS X El Capitan 10.11.2

I am trying to run 'bundle exec jekyll serve' but it seems that I had to run a bundle install.  This is where the install errors-out

```
Installing redcarpet 3.3.3 (was 3.3.2) with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/TLuu/Documents/Sides/theresaluu.github.io/vendor/bundle/gems/redcarpet-3.3.3/ext/redcarpet
/Users/TLuu/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160101-37132-138gbyg.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/TLuu/Documents/Sides/theresaluu.github.io/vendor/bundle/gems/redcarpet-3.3.3/ext/redcarpet
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/TLuu/Documents/Sides/theresaluu.github.io/vendor/bundle/gems/redcarpet-3.3.3/ext/redcarpet
make "DESTDIR="
compiling autolink.c
couldn't understand kern.osversion `15.2.0'
In file included from autolink.c:23:
buffer.h:29:20: error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
In file included from autolink.c:23:
buffer.h:47: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘uint8_t’
In file included from autolink.c:24:
autolink.h:37: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
autolink.h:41: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uint8_t’
autolink.h:45: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uint8_t’
autolink.h:49: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uint8_t’
autolink.c:26:20: error: string.h: No such file or directory
autolink.c:27:20: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
autolink.c:28:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
autolink.c:29:19: error: ctype.h: No such file or directory
autolink.c:36: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
autolink.c:58: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
autolink.c:142: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
autolink.c:171: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uint8_t’
autolink.c: In function ‘sd_autolink__www’:
autolink.c:178: error: ‘data’ undeclared (first use in this function)
autolink.c:178: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
autolink.c:178: error: for each function it appears in.)
autolink.c:181: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
autolink.c: At top level:
autolink.c:207: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uint8_t’
autolink.c: In function ‘sd_autolink__email’:
autolink.c:216: error: ‘uint8_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
autolink.c:216: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘c’
autolink.c:218: error: ‘c’ undeclared (first use in this function)
autolink.c:221: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strchr’
autolink.c:231: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘c’
autolink.c:247: error: ‘data’ undeclared (first use in this function)
autolink.c: At top level:
autolink.c:262: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uint8_t’
autolink.c: In function ‘sd_autolink__url’:
autolink.c:269: error: ‘data’ undeclared (first use in this function)
autolink.c:278: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
make: *** [autolink.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/TLuu/Documents/Sides/theresaluu.github.io/vendor/bundle/gems/redcarpet-3.3.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/TLuu/Documents/Sides/theresaluu.github.io/vendor/bundle/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.0.0-static/redcarpet-3.3.3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing redcarpet (3.3.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install redcarpet -v '3.3.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I suspect that this is a problem the arose from the last OS X update (Dec 15, 2015).

Comment: Have you updated your XCode / CLI tools since upgrading to El Capitan? A bit of superficial Googling suggests your `gcc` may be out of date.

Comment: Thanks @Alex! I thought I already looked at that when I went to the app store to see if there were any updates and when I opened up XCode to see if there were any prompts to update, but it turns out there is no warning for that.  I used the following command to update my command line tools `$ xcode-select --install` Thanks, again.